# Position: “absolute” in React Native not working

Tags: react-native

How can I use the `position: “absolute”` style for `ScrollView` in React Native?

I use this code to display a blank page:

```
<ScrollView style={{flex:1}}>
    <View
         style={{
           position:"absolute",
           top:0,
           right:0,
           width:100,
           height:100,
           backgroundColor:'red',
         }}
    />
   ....
   ....
   ....
</ScrollView>
```

Comment: can you please explain more what you want to achieve with this code??

Comment: Adding to what @RajatGupta said can you also post an example of how that code is not working ? Looks fine to me